# @font-face, google fonts and SEO

Tags: seo, fonts, web-crawlers

Someone I know claims that search engines like Google have trouble with fonts that aren't the old standard fonts of yesteryear, resulting in pages not getting parsed by search spiders,  and that to be on the safe side SEO wise I should stick with the standbys like Arial.  A quick google search for 'search engines can't read fonts' yielded zilch. Do search engine spiders actually ignore text formatted with fonts they do not recognize?

Comment: A recent video (7 May 2012) from Matt Cutts on... [How does Google view font replacement?](http://youtu.be/hb4LYWxXESY)

Comment: +1 for the link.  I ALWAYS like to hear the answer from The Matt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and no, he's conflating two different things.

In late 90's/early 2000's, when designers needed to use fonts for design reasons, they embedded graphics files in HTML pages. Search engines cannot understand these, nor can the screen readers used by blind and partially sighted people. This is because the only HTML code in the page for a menu link, for example, would be something like

`<div><a href="#"><img src="menu-title.gif" /></a></div>`

which is meaningless to a robot that *at the time* could only decipher plain old HTML, ignoring the CSS and tags. The fix in that era was to write the code like this

`<div><a href="#"><img src="menu-title.gif" /><span class="text-indent">Menu Title</span></a></div>`

and use CSS like this

`.text-indent { text-indent: -5000px; }`

to shift the text out of the part of the page visible to a sighted user. This meant that search engines would get the information they needed to understand the context of the link without interrupting the visual.

These days you can use technologies like [embedded fonts](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/05/03/understanding-and-using-embedded-fonts-what-why-and-how/) or [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) to augment your designs. These render parts of text from the HTML document as an anti-aliased font, but leave the HTML code intact, therefore search engines (and screen readers), can parse the text.

Overall he's wrong on both counts, provided the relevant textual information is available in plain text HTML search engines will understand your page and links - the fonts/graphics are immaterial.

He's also wrong about the groups (from the sound of it he's a blow hard) anyone with access to Google can figure this out.

Comment: You can also use `alt` and/or `title` attributes to indicate the contents of an image: `<img src="menu-title.gif" alt="Menu Title" />`

Comment: but Google will treat it differently - as an image description, not part of the text

Comment: @joshuahedlund As Jacek indicates, these types of information do not replace real text and are not really informative for visually disabled users given the way they actually use the web.

Comment: If an image has `alt` text, the text _will_ be treated by screen readers, search engines, text-only browsers, etc. as text content. That's the whole purpose of having _alternative_ text content. Google will parse & search `alt` text, and they will include it in the text flow and treat it as anchor text in the case of image links.

Comment: However, the `title` attribute is not the same as `alt`. `title` is designed to give additional advisory info about an element. It's usually shown as a tool-tip but will _not_ be treated as an alternative textual representation of the image content by search engines, screen readers, etc. That's why most a11y groups advise against using `title` as a substitute for `alt` or using redundant `title` attributes that just repeat the image text.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté you're correct, but most blind users will listen to the heading tags first, then the links, and ignore the images. Screen readers have grown up around the fact that alt and title are much abused.

Comment: Actually, JAWS, and I'm pretty sure NVDA, reads `alt` text by default. They only fall back on the filename if `alt` is missing. The most common problem with `alt` attributes is that they're missing or the author simply repeats the filename there. The only sites "abusing" `alt` attributes are spammy sites, and there's nothing a screen reader can do to make such sites any less spammy. As a side note, if you want screen readers to ignore a decorative image, the standard convention for most screen readers is to explicitly specify an `alt` attribute of `""`.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté true JAWS, SuperNova and NVDA can read them, but what I was referring to is that if you watch blind users operate the software they generally list headings first and then anchors (in fact they're trained to do this). By abused I mean that they're often not completed, uninformative or simply wrong.

Comment: BTW, did not know that title attributes didn't get seen as text content...tho it makes sense, since I mainly use it for <a> tags (which should be optimized for SEO anyways, cough cough).

Comment: I don't think that's them ignoring images so much as just skimming the navigation layout of the page. If you have an image in a heading, then the `alt` would be read as any other part of the heading text. If it's linked, then the `alt` gets read as the anchor text. Otherwise, the `img` is simply part of your body content, and the `alt` is inserted in that text flow. If the screen reader reads that part of the page, it will not skip the `alt`. However, if the screen reader isn't reading that body content, then, no, it won't automatically read out all the `alt` text on the page by default.

Comment: Though to be honest, I've never watched a regular screen reader user browse the web. However, I _am_ subscribed to the WebAIM mailing list; and the impression I've gotten from the list is that `alt` text is a critically important part of web accessibility. I've never gotten the impression that screen reader users routinely ignore images altogether.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I've been trained on JAWS and, in the past worked as an accessibility developer, I also have a close friend who is a blind web dev. The view is that improper use of alt and title has rendered them useless to most visually disabled users (though they are a critical part of the standard) and the tools evolved to take that into account. So the users use heading tags to get a sense of where they are on the page and then look at the links to figure out where to go. Alt is only helpful if the page is confusing. It's amazing to watch!

Answer (score 5):

Search engines don't read fonts. They don't "see" pages. They read text. They read semantic markup. They try to find relationships. Fonts are completely useless and irrelevant to them.